# Ldap authentication using django_auth_ldap

Tags: python, django, ldap, django-auth-ldap

I am trying to achieve Ldap authentication using django.
For that I have configured my settings.py as mentioned here http://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/example.html

I am attaching my settings.py file here

```
import ldap
import os
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch
# Django settings for mysite project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
# ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

AUTH_LDAP_CONNECTION_OPTIONS = {
ldap.OPT_REFERRALS: 0
}

AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "cn=admin,dc=server,dc=com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = ""
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=People,dc=server,dc=com",ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s")

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://ldap.server.com"
AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER = False

MANAGERS = ADMINS

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'nameofdatabase',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
    'USER': 'someuser',
    'PASSWORD': 'somepassword',
    'HOST': '/tmp/mysql.sock',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
    'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
}
}

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True


SITE_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
#MEDIA_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"

STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'some_secret_key'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
# 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
# Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
     'django.contrib.admindocs',
     'polls',
    #'ldapauthentication'
    'portal',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
             'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
     }
},
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
}
}
```

Is there anything else apart to do from this ?

My views.py file is as follows

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django_auth_ldap.backend import LDAPBackend
# Create your views here.

@login_required
@csrf_protect
def portal_main_page(request):
    """
    If users are authenticated, direct them to the main page. Otherwise, take
    them to the login page.
    """
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user.is_authenticated()
        return render_to_response('portal/index.html')
```

My models.py file is empty. I am simply not able to authenticate the users?

What else do I need to do. From what I found out it is just trying to authenticate against the local database. I could not get any further help from http://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/#auth-ldap-bind-as-authenticating-user

I have checked similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669161/how-to-achieve-authentication-with-django-auth-ldap?rq=1) but could not make out anything from the answers from the users.

Kindly Help me, so that I can achieve the authentication.

Comment: where you able to make it work?